# Amazon S3 read file timeout

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, scipy, timeout

I'm newbie.

I want to get attributes of the audio file (.wav) on S3 using **scipy** like this:

```
import boto3
from scipy.io import wavfile
from io import BytesIO
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

content = s3.get_object(Bucket=BUCKET, Key=key)['Body']
data = content.read() # GOT timeout here
wrapper = BytesIO(data)
samplerate, audio_file = wavfile.read(wrapper)
```

I tested with some files on S3 (50MB, 112MB, 150MB) and I got a timeout with 112MB, 150MB at **content.read()**

Any idea for this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the connection timeout and the socket timeout in your client configuration.
[Click here for reference model](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/aws-sdk-for-java-tips-and-tricks/)
,here is an example of how to do it in  AWS SDK 1.9.3

```
ClientConfiguration config = new ClientConfiguration(); 
config.setConnectionTimeout(connectionTimeout);
config.setSocketTimeout(readTimeout); 
AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, config);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response. Where can I use this example? and how?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the below method to your code.

```
@SuppressWarnings("checkstyle:hiddenfield")
public ClientConfiguration withConnectionTimeout(int connectionTimeout) {
setConnectionTimeout(connectionTimeout);
return this;
}
```

Comment: Let me try. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I used here:
**Download** file instead of streaming it into memory (**read()**)
It means:

```
os.mkdir('/tmp/file') # create dir by os library
path = '/tmp/file.example.wav'
s3.download_file(Bucket, key, path) # download file from s3
samplerate, audio_file = wavfile.read(path)

Beside the point, as I researched, use `mutagen` is better `scipy`
```

I think this is the solution that is quite good and easier
I wanna just share this for anyone who needed

With the @Anwesha's solution, maybe it's good but it is hard to understand for a person like me